# Iterate over rows and update column values based on conditions in Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have database for the changes made for given issue Id at any given date . The values in  changed_parameter are the parameters for which the changes were made .

Its old value and new value for the changed parameter are updated in  old_value new_value columns respectively

| Issue_Id | Due_Date | status | estimation_hour | changed_date | changed_parameter | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 20 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/16/2023 | estimation_hour | 20 | 30 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/16/2023 | Due_Date | 1/20/2023 | 1/31/2023 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 40 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 30 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 50 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |

So now I have to create a snapshot of the issues id at changed dates based on above data

So my final table should look like this

| Issue_Id | Due_Date | status | estimation_hour | changed_date | changed_parameter | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1/20/2023 | Accepted | 0 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 101 | 1/20/2023 | Accepted | 20 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 20 |
| 101 | 1/20/2023 | Accepted | 30 | 1/16/2023 | estimation_hour | 20 | 30 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | Accepted | 30 | 1/16/2023 | Due_Date | 1/20/2023 | 1/31/2023 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | InProgress | 30 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | InProgress | 40 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 40 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | Accepted | 0 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | Accepted | 30 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 30 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | InProgress | 30 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | InProgress | 50 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 50 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |

I had updated the above data in pandas dataframe and iterated over each row.

In each iteration I updated old value of changed parameter to previously available rows of that issue ID and  till the same . new value was updated to current row as follows

iterating over each row is time consuming

1st Iteration

| Issue_Id | Due_Date | status | estimation_hour | changed_date | changed_parameter | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | Accepted | 40 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 20 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/16/2023 | estimation_hour | 20 | 30 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/16/2023 | Due_Date | 1/20/2023 | 1/31/2023 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 40 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 30 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 50 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |

2nd  Iteration

| Issue_Id | Due_Date | status | estimation_hour | changed_date | changed_parameter | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | Accepted | 0 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 20 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 20 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/16/2023 | estimation_hour | 20 | 30 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/16/2023 | Due_Date | 1/20/2023 | 1/31/2023 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 40 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 30 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 50 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |

3rd  Iteration

| Issue_Id | Due_Date | status | estimation_hour | changed_date | changed_parameter | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | Accepted | 0 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 20 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 20 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 30 | 1/16/2023 | estimation_hour | 20 | 30 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/16/2023 | Due_Date | 1/20/2023 | 1/31/2023 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 40 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 30 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 50 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |

4th  Iteration

| Issue_Id | Due_Date | status | estimation_hour | changed_date | changed_parameter | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1/20/2023 | Accepted | 0 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 101 | 1/20/2023 | closed | 20 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 20 |
| 101 | 1/20/2023 | closed | 30 | 1/16/2023 | estimation_hour | 20 | 30 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/16/2023 | Due_Date | 1/20/2023 | 1/31/2023 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 40 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 30 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 50 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |

5th  Iteration

| Issue_Id | Due_Date | status | estimation_hour | changed_date | changed_parameter | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1/20/2023 | Accepted | 0 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 101 | 1/20/2023 | Accepted | 20 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 20 |
| 101 | 1/20/2023 | Accepted | 30 | 1/16/2023 | estimation_hour | 20 | 30 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | Accepted | 40 | 1/16/2023 | Due_Date | 1/20/2023 | 1/31/2023 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | InProgress | 40 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 40 |
| 101 | 1/31/2023 | closed | 40 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/10/2023 | status | Defined | Accepted |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/15/2023 | estimation_hour | 0 | 30 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/20/2023 | status | Accepted | InProgress |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/25/2023 | estimation_hour | 30 | 50 |
| 102 | 2/28/2023 | closed | 50 | 1/30/2023 | status | InProgress | Closed |

and so on..

Comment: You can learn a bunch of iteration techniques [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270285/4561887). I present 13 or more, covering a variety of scenarios.

Comment: This seems to be more information than necessary. Can you perhaps reduce to just the first 2 or 3 iterations?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your case is not so trivial, you need to reshape your dataframe then group by `Issue_Id` then update the values. Since your data frame is sorted by "changed_date", the idea is to fill new values forward and fill old values backward. If the parameter is missing, simply fill in with the existing values:

```
def update_values(df):
    return df['new_value'].ffill().fillna(df['old_value'].bfill())
        
upd_values = (df.pivot_table(index=df.index, columns='changed_parameter',
                             values=['old_value', 'new_value'], aggfunc='first')
                .groupby(df['Issue_Id']).apply(update_values)
                .droplevel('Issue_Id').fillna(df))

df[upd_values.columns] = upd_values
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Issue_Id   Due_Date      status  estimation_hour changed_date changed_parameter   old_value   new_value
0        101  1/20/2023    Accepted                0    1/10/2023            status     Defined    Accepted
1        101  1/20/2023    Accepted               20    1/15/2023   estimation_hour           0          20
2        101  1/20/2023    Accepted               30    1/16/2023   estimation_hour          20          30
3        101  1/31/2023    Accepted               30    1/16/2023          Due_Date   1/20/2023   1/31/2023
4        101  1/31/2023  InProgress               30    1/20/2023            status    Accepted  InProgress
5        101  1/31/2023  InProgress               40    1/25/2023   estimation_hour          30          40
6        101  1/31/2023      Closed               40    1/30/2023            status  InProgress      Closed
7        102  2/28/2023    Accepted                0    1/10/2023            status     Defined    Accepted
8        102  2/28/2023    Accepted               30    1/15/2023   estimation_hour           0          30
9        102  2/28/2023  InProgress               30    1/20/2023            status    Accepted  InProgress
10       102  2/28/2023  InProgress               50    1/25/2023   estimation_hour          30          50
11       102  2/28/2023      Closed               50    1/30/2023            status  InProgress      Closed
```

---

**Old answer**

```
old_value = pd.to_numeric(df['old_value'], errors='coerce').shift(-1)
new_value = pd.to_numeric(df['new_value'], errors='coerce')

df['estimation_hour'] = old_value.fillna(new_value).ffill().convert_dtypes()
df['status'] = df['new_value'].mask(new_value.notna()).ffill()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Issue_Id      status  estimation_hour changed_date changed_parameter   old_value   new_value
0       101    Accepted                0    1/10/2023            status     Defined    Accepted
1       101    Accepted               20    1/15/2023   estimation_hour           0          20
2       101  InProgress               20    1/20/2023            status    Accepted  InProgress
3       101  InProgress               40    1/25/2023   estimation_hour          20          40
4       101      Closed               40    1/30/2023            status  InProgress      Closed
5       102    Accepted                0    1/10/2023            status     Defined    Accepted
6       102    Accepted               30    1/15/2023   estimation_hour           0          30
7       102  InProgress               30    1/20/2023            status    Accepted  InProgress
8       102  InProgress               50    1/25/2023   estimation_hour          30          50
9       102      Closed               50    1/30/2023            status  InProgress      Closed
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien thanks for the answer . Here currently the change in parameters are alternative. There may be chances that same change parameter may be repeated successively .So in that case u r answers works..?

Comment: Hi   Corralien  @jezrael I have updated the description . Plz can u provide answer for it now..?

Comment: @ShivarajMath. I updated my answer. The idea is the same except that you have to reshape your dataframe first. Can you check my answer, please?

Comment: Hi @Corralien yes . It works fine . Thank you very much